# UML relationships with generics and nullable fields

Tags: java, c#, c++, generics, uml

(0) When a class `Foo` contains a field of type `Predicate<Bar>` or something like it, what would `Foo`'s relationship be with `Bar`?

```
class Foo {
    Predicate<Bar> validator;
}
```

(1) If a class `Foo` contains a generic container (not necessarily a list; might be a box of one `Bar`) of `Bar`, what is `Foo`'s relationship with `Bar`?

```
class Foo {
    SomethingThatHasA<Bar> barContainer;
}
```

(2) If a class `Foo` has a nullable member of type `Bar`, does `Foo` merely have a dependency on, have an association with, or is a composition of `Bar`?

```
class Foo {
    Bar bar; // may be null
}
```

(3) (This might make more sense in C++ than elsewhere) If a class `Foo` would normally be composed by a `Bar` object (i.e. can't live without a `Bar`), but is allowed to have a default constructor that zeroes out/nullifies all its fields as a kind of blank slate state that has no use until filled in later, would `Foo` still have a composition relationship with `Bar`?

```
class Foo {
  private:
    Bar* bar; // or possibly just a non-pointer Bar
  public:
    Foo() : bar(nullptr) {}
    Foo(/* whatever */) : bar(/* something */) {}
};
```

Comment: In `class Foo { Bar bar;}` `bar` cannot be `null`. Did you mean `class Foo { Bar* bar;}` or am I missing something?

Comment: @tobi303 Culprit is the language tag spamming. In Java and C# `Bar` can be `null`.

Comment: My apologies, only the scenario in (3) is in C++

Comment: ah, ok. Actually the comment ("may be null") was quite clear

Comment: Why mark as duplicate?

Comment: @AliciaRose In the duplicates answer it's well illustrated what you've been asking for. If there's more, you may edit your question which will bump it for reopening.

Comment: It does not seem to be the same as my question, since I'm asking about nullables as well.

Answer (score 1):

(0) and (1) : A UML dependency would be appropriate here: a dashed arrow pointing from Foo to Bar.

(2) At least an association. If the meaning of Foo and Bar is such, that Bar can be considered to be a part of Foo, then you may use an aggregation (open diamond), for example in case of a Car and an Engine. If, in addition, instances of Bars referred to by Foos do not live longer than their Foos, then you may use a composition (filled diamond), even though not every Foo has a Bar and even though not every Bar is contained in a Foo.

(3) Yes

Answer (score 0):

(0) none - `Foo` just know to validate instances of Bar through validator.

(3) Yes. `Foo`-s with invalid `Bar`s are in the undead category (because... i.e. can't live without a Bar)